# Magento 2.3.2 Display OOS products in configuration product option

Tags: magento2.3.2

We are using Magento 2.3.2.

I found that there is an issue with configurable products.

We use the Text Swatch and the Dropdown options and currently, If an item is OOS, the finish or size disappears from the product page.

In some instances all variations are OOS and there is nothing showing.

Is there any way for the Dropdown option we can have the OOS products showing but add a `- Out of Stock`?

See: reference image
[image]

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a built-in config to allow displaying out-of-stock products. You can see it in:
Go to admin > Stores > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options

Set Display Out of Stock Products to YES

In case you want to add text you need to customize the product detail page